# Calculating the number of '1's in a df

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df, illustrated as the matrix in the image, and I would like to count the number of 'correlated' squares which are equal to 1, and 'non correlated' which are equal to 0.

I have tried to use the df.count() function but it doesn't return the result I want, as in the totals of 1s and 0s.

Any help would be great, thank you.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

df = pd.read_csv('Res_Gov.csv')  

df1 = df.set_index('Indicators').T 

# Set up the matplotlib figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))

colors = ["#f4a261","#2a9d8f"] 
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom', colors, len(colors))

# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
df1 = sns.heatmap(df1, cmap=cmap, square=True,
                  linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})  # HERE

# Set the colorbar labels
ax.set_xlabel("Indicators")
ax.set_ylabel("Resilience Criteria")
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks([0.25,0.75])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(['Not Correlated', 'Correlated'])
fig.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

DF snippet

```
,Indicators,Robustness,Flexibility,Resourcefulness,Redundancy,Diversity,Independence,Foresight Capacity,Coordination Capacitiy,Collaboration Capacity,Connectivity & Interdependence,Agility,Adaptability,Self-Organization,Creativity & Innovation,Efficiency,Equity
0,G1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1
1,G2,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1
2,G3,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1
3,G4,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1
4,G5,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0
5,G6,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1
6,G7,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
7,G8,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
8,G9,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1
9,G10,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1
10,G11,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1
11,G12,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0
12,G13,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
13,G14,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1
14,G15,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1
15,G16,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1
16,G17,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0
17,G18,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1
18,G19,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
19,G20,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1
20,G21,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1
21,G22,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1
22,G23,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0
```

Matrix :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reshape to Series and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.melt('Indicators')['value'].value_counts()
```

Or:

```
df.drop(columns='Indicators').stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
1    208
0    160
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for 1 in a dataframe like this:

`df==1`

This returns a dataframe with boolean values (True, False) of the same size as the initial dataframe indicating if the condition is fulfilled for each cell.

Chaining the result of this logical statement with `.values` and `.sum()` will return the number of 1s in the dataframe.

```
(df==1).values.sum()
```

The `.values` command returns the dataframe with boolean values as a numpy array and `.sum()` makes a summation over the whole array counting False as 0 and True as 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `df1`:

```
>>> df1.stack().value_counts()
1    208
0    160
dtype: int64
```

You can also use `numpy`:

```
>>> dict(zip(*np.unique(df1, return_counts=True)))
{0: 160, 1: 208}

>>> pd.Series(dict(zip(*np.unique(df1, return_counts=True))))
0    160
1    208
dtype: int64
```